A functional equation with functions of class $C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$
Find all functions $f \in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$
f(x)^{2} = \int_{0}^{x} (f(t)^{2}+f'(t)^{2}) dt + 2022
$$
for all $x$ real.
My attempt: If $f \in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ is a solution, then
$$
2f(x)f'(x) = f(x)^{2}+f'(x)^{2}.
$$
Thus
$$
0 = f(x)^{2}-2f'(x)f(x)+f'(x)^{2} = (f(x)-f'(x))^{2}.
$$
This implies that $f(x) = f'(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so $f(x) = ce^{x}$ for some $c \in\mathbb{R}$.
I don´t know why but when I substitute the solution I don´t get the equality. Is my reasoning correct? Should I justify why $f$ has to be a scalar multiple of the exponential map?

Your reasoning is mostly correct. Substituting $f(x)=ce^x$ into the original equation, we get:
$$c^2 e^{2x} = \int_{0}^{x} \left(c^2 e^{2t} + c^2 e^{2t}\right) dt + 2022.$$
$$c^2 e^{2x} = \left.c^2 e^{2t}\right|_0^x + 2022,$$
$$c^2 e^{2x} = c^2 e^{2x}-c^2 + 2022,$$
$$c = \pm\sqrt{2022}.$$
So we have two possible solutions:
$$f(x)=\sqrt{2022}~e^x,\quad f(x)=-\sqrt{2022}~e^x.$$

I see, I should also say what for what $c$ it holds. Thank you.
